# Lex file unrecognized rule

Tags: linux, lex

I am trying to run the following program, and am getting unrecognized rule: 37. Not sure why it is giving me that error in line 37.

Command: $ lex mycsv2html.l

```
%{                      //Definition Section 

#include <stdin.h>                         
#include <stdout.h>
int c;
extern int yylval;
%}


%%                      // Rule Section
" "       ;
[\n]     {
            c = yytext[0];
            yylval = c - '\n';
            return(br);
          }
["]     {
            c = yytext[0];
            yylval = c - '';
            return('');
          }
[<]     {
            c = yytext[0];
            yylval = c - '';
            return('&lt');
          }

[>]     {
            c = yytext[0];
            yylval = c - '';
            return('&gt');
          }

int main(void)                            //C Code Section
{
    /* Call the lexer, then quit. */
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll find it much simpler for special-character rules just to return yytext[0] and refer to them as literals in the grammar, e.g. "<". That way you can also write a single rule for all of them instead of multiple rules. You can even use . as the pattern, which leaves the job of dealing with illegal characters to the parser, which is much better able to deal with error recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `%%` between the second part (rules) and the third part(C codes).

```
.....
[>]     {
        c = yytext[0];
        yylval = c - '';
        return('&gt');
      }

%% // HERE

int main(void)                            //C Code Section
.....
```